# Android facebook sdk, how to post custom statuses with links and photos

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

With facebook android sdk 3.0, which method do I use to post custom status messages that contain links and link previews, summaries, and a personal message?

I have ironed out which permissions I need, the `publish_stream` and `publish_actions` permissions (which may be redundant, based on a facebook blog post dated April 25th, 2013), but now with the `Request` object, I am not sure which method to call.

Below are the methods within the `Request` object:

[image]

I tried using the intuitively named `newStatusUpdateRequest` method, but I am limited to only passing in a string. Would encoding a link inside this string accompany the message and be autoparsed to include the photo thumbnail, title header and summary? In previous Facebook SDKs this had to be explicitly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use most of them. Most of these methods only presets some params for you.

```
Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(session, postEntity.getMessage(), listener);

Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
parameters.putString("link", "Your link");
parameters.putString("description", "Description");
parameters.putString("name", "Name");
parameters.putString("picture", "Picture link");

request.executeAndWait();
```

Comment: okay, where is `parameters` passed into the request object? and what type is `postEntity`

Comment: You already take parameters object from request `request.getParameters();` so you don't need to set it again